# Generate "reliable" random numbers in Javascript. (No collisions)

Tags: javascript, random, guid, uuid, string-hashing

Would like to generate some random strings to be used as database keys.

Essentially these will be UUIDs, however they do not need to conform to any particular spec aside from the necessary 122-128 bits of randomness.

Most of the code will run in a browser. As I understand it, Javascript running with a browser cannot be trusted to properly seed its random number generator. Instead I was hoping to seed the random number generator with some random data from the server, then generate multiple "UUIDs" starting from that seed.

Is there a good random number generator that can be used for this purpose?

Comment: Try [crypto.getRandomValues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.crypto.getRandomValues) and falling back on Math.random

Comment: I would recommend using a server side component for reliable random things in JavaScript.

Comment: Random and Unique are hard to get together (short of shuffling, but it gives you limited number of items). Consider if simple auto-increment (with possible server-side range allocation) is enough.

Comment: For true random number generation you should use the WebAPI provided by http://random.org/

Comment: (Math.random() * performance.now()).toString(36)